# Displaying unresolved maven dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies

Each time maven runs it fails because I'm missing a depedency, something like

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project foo:
>   Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.foo:foo:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.foo.test >
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.foo.bar:foo-bar:jar:2.0:
>   Could not find artifact
>   org.usa.trump:trump-usa:pom:10.0
>   in central (https://path/to/repo/) -> [Help 1]

In this case it traverses the dependencies and ultimately can't find

`org.usa.trump:trump-usa:pom:10.0`

So I fix the issue with this dependency's missing artifact but then I run mvn again and it fails with another missing dependency.

I'm trying to automate fixing these dependency resolutions but I don't want to have to run multiple mvn executions after each time I fix one, just to find out what the next missing one is.

Is there way to get maven to spit out all missing dependencies at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your idea is that your missing dependency might have other dependencies, and maven cannot know them before you actually make that artifact available. So a complete solution is not possible. A partial solution may, depending on why you miss so many artifacts and how your fixture procedure works.

We had the situation that full access to MavenCentral was not allowed and artifacts needed to be copied from MavenCentral to a company repository. I constructed a script that copied the artifacts together with all transitive dependencies - in this way I could avoid most of the iterative "missing artifacts" problems.

Comment: Ya That was my scenario as well ( using new repository ).  I took an approach of writing a script to clone each repo and run a clean install.  For each failure, it would parse the output then create a list for each missing dependency.  Then download it from our old repo and upload it the repo, then repeat this process N times for each repo since it could fail the next run again with another dependency.  I could have took your approach but I wanted to pull public dependencies via maven so that we could build our cache in our new repo.

Comment: ..I suppose I could have still took your approach and just built in logic to identify internal vs external and then only upload internal but this way I was able to ensure the clean install worked.  To each his own I suppose.  In hindsight I may have went the route you went.  I've accepted the answer.  I was hoping for a silver bullet some hidden gem about maven I didn't know, but that's not the case.